# DNN module control doesnt' use page template

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have module which is a list of elements. I want to be able to click in a element and go to a control which show detailed information and stuff.

Problem is that when I go to that control the asigned page template is changed; don't know if it normal behavior and if it is: how do I force the asigned template?

NOTE: I don't want to change the admin template in order to achieve that

Hope it is enough information and help some people in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found was "[Dynamically Loaded Controls](http://adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/Misc/ModuleNavigationOptions.htm#Dynamically_Loaded_Controls)"

A developer can use a placeholder control on their module:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="phDynamicPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and dynamically load a control into the placeholder.

```
Select Case Me.rblDynamicControl.SelectedValue
    Case 1
        DynamicPage = DotNetNuke.Common.ResolveUrl(Me.TemplateSourceDirectory & "/DynamicControls/control1.ascx")
    Case 2
        DynamicPage = DotNetNuke.Common.ResolveUrl(Me.TemplateSourceDirectory & "/DynamicControls/control2.ascx")
End Select

Dim objModule As Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase = CType(Me.LoadControl(DynamicPage), DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase)

If Not objModule Is Nothing Then
    objModule.ModuleConfiguration = Me.ModuleConfiguration
    phDynamicPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(objModule)
End If
```